# INDEX MATCH formula in Excel returning incorrect results in some cells and correct results in others

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, max, match

Before I start I will say that I cannot post the actual spreadsheet as it contains confidential data.

I have a spreadsheet to record sports carnival data and calculate House and age champions.

The spreadsheet has columns F "gender", K "name", L "age" and N "score".
I am using the following formula to generate champions in each age and gender group (eg 12 year old female, 12 year old male, 13 year old female, etc)

=INDEX($K$2:$K$1000,MATCH(MAXIFS($N$2:$N$1000,$F$2:$F$1000,"F",$L$2:$L$1000,"12"),$N$2:$N$1000,0))

where the "F" changes to "M" and the "12" changes to the various age groups.

The formula returns correct results for "F" "12", "16" and "17" but incorrect for "F" "13", "14" and "15". And a similar combination for the male age champions. The incorrect result 'name' is both the wrong gender and the wrong age.

I have tried several different 'fixes' including text/number alternatives and different formulas to solve the problem but the incorrect result keeps recurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what way are the results for F 13, etc "incorrect"? In that scenario, what does the MaxIFS function return? Is that incorrect? What does the Match return? Is that incorrect? Or is the Index incorrect? Basic troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Formula Evaluation tool on the Formulas ribbon to step through the formula that returns "incorrect" results.

You will see what MAXIFS resolves to. You will see what MATCH resolves to.

I would assume that the number returned by MAXIFS is not a unique value, so the MATCH function finds the **first** match for that value, and that may be for the wrong age group and gender.

If you are using Office 365, then you have the new Dynamic Array functions. In that case, you can use

```
=INDEX(FILTER(K2:K10,(F2:F10="m")*(L2:L10=13)),MATCH(MAX(FILTER(N2:N10,(F2:F10="m")*(L2:L10=13))),FILTER(N2:N10,(F2:F10="m")*(L2:L10=13)),0))
```

The screenshot shows the formula in action. Cell Q2 shows your formula, returning the wrong result "girl4", which is a match for the result returned by MAXIFS.

Cell Q3 has the formula using Filter, which applies the same filter to the match as to the MAX function.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The Formula Evaluation shows that the MAXIFS is correct, however, the MATCH is returning the first instance of the MAXIFS value not the instance that matches the correct age and gender - is there a way to return the matching value with the correct age and gender?